# Pixel 4a makes a mystery sound with no notification

Tags: notifications, audio

*Note:* This is similar to [Mystery "notification" sound](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171359/mystery-notification-sound), but not the same symptoms, so I believe it is a different thing.

## My issue

For about the past month, my phone has made a mystery sound almost every day.  Video of it occurring here: https://youtu.be/cP4fYYouaAg.  It typically happens some time after 9am, and it comes with no notification.  As far as I can tell, there's no visual indication of what's happening at all.  Does anyone know what this sound is??

### My phone

Google Pixel 4a on Mint Mobile.  Formerly T-Mobile prepaid.

### Things I've tried

- searched through all of the phone's built-in notification sounds.  This isn't one of them(!)
- turned off NFC, still happens.
- turned off bluetooth, still happens.
- noted location that it happens, doesn't matter (not consistent).  Note that when I say location, I mean both geographic location and the phone's proximity to other devices (neither seem to matter).
- noted times of occurrences.  Not consistent.  Doesn't happen every day, but on the days it does occur, it's usually between 9am and 9:30am CST.
- I wrote down the exact second that this happened one day, then searched the phone's developer logs from **adb logcat -b all.**  There were a handful of entries in the seconds surrounding the event, but all of those entries are common occurrences throughout the logs, so they can't be associated with this.  In short: this sound leaves no trace in the phone's internal logs.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: check [find my device](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) and let device ring

Comment: Was the phone connected to charger when it made that sound? People report that as a reason when aftermarket or poor charge connection //Though you disabled NFC, remove all NFC cards from the phone case or nearby. Ditto for anything else that is NFC enabled (books fur example) // some people say it's due to weather app updating its status. Uninstall weather apps //Welcome to the site, good first question

Answer (score 1):

Following a suggestion from a user on a different forum, I put the phone into safe mode for a few days.  This deactivates all external apps.  (In the power menu, long-press the power off option.)  While in safe mode, the phone never made the sound, which proves that it is some external app.

I am currently in the process of uninstalling my external apps, starting from the most recent.  Each day, if the phone still makes the noise, I uninstall the next one.  I am bound to find the offending app eventually.  (Note: yesterday, I uninstalled Duolingo and it didn't make the noise today, so this may well be it.  Couple more days to be sure...)

Final thought: why would an app do this?  Though I have no direct evidence of this yet, I suspect that an external app was giving me a lot of notifications, so I must have long-pressed one of those to silence that app's notifications, but somehow, the sound is still getting through.  Perhaps a bug is present in that app.

Thanks for suggestions above!

Comment: Did you ever find out what it was? Was it Duolingo? I also have the app and also getting these phantom notifications

Comment: I did figure it out, and it wasn't Duolingo after all.  Unfortunately, I don't remember off hand which app it ended up being.  Safe mode is your friend.  Take notes and use a binary search.  (uninstall half of your apps each iteration, until you detect a change in behavior.)